# Sum of a geometric series of functions: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

$$\text{Let }f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} \text{ for } x\in\Bbb{R}$$

$$\text{I found }\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) = x^2+1 \text{ since it is a geometric series}$$
Now I'm asked to find $a<b$ such that the series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

I'm inclined to say $a>-\infty$ and $b<\infty$ since for $|x|\ne\infty$,  $x^2+1$ is finite. Is this logic sufficient??

Comment: Hello - For $x = 0$ the series equals 0 and for $x = 1$ it converges to 2. So you should check your work. There may be separate cases. As to an interval of convergence, your logic is defective since by the same argument the series $\sum_{k \ge 0} (1+x^2)^k$ would also converge for all real $x$, and that is  definitely not the case.

Comment: So for $x\ne0$ the series converges to $x^2+1$ which is a closed form expression. That's why I figured it was uniformly convergent on $[a,b]\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: That's correct so far. To find an interval of convergence, note that this is a geometric series $\sum_{n}A q^n$. What is $A$? What is therefore $q$? And for which $x$ is $|q| < 1$? That should get you to an answer.

Comment: $A=x^2$ and $q=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$, now $|q|<1 \implies \frac{1}{|(1+x^2)|}<1$ which holds for $|x|>0$ i.e the series converges uniformly for $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall: A sequence of functions $g_m\to g$ uniformly on some domain $U$ if and only if $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{x\in U}|g_m(x)-g(x)|=0$.

In this case, let $g_m(x)=\sum_{n=0}^m f_n(x)$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=1+x^2$. By straight forward calculation we have
$$|g_m(x)-g(x)|=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^m}$$

Since $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$ is continuous on any $[a,b]$, it attains a maximum value $\leq 1$. However, if $[a,b]$ contains $0$, then

$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}=1$$

and in this case $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{x\in U}|g_m(x)-g(x)|=1$, thus the convergence is not uniform.

If $[a,b]$ does not contain $0$, the convergence is uniform since in this case
$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}<1$$

Comment: @Dr.MV using the formula $\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n=\frac{1}{1-q}$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=x^2\frac{1}{1-(1+x^2)^{-1}}=x^2\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}=1+x^2$, thus $|g_m(x)-g(x)|=\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=(1+x^2)^{-m-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=(1+x^2)^{-m}$, which is exactly what I got.

Comment: Yes.  When one performs calculations in one's head and it is late at night, then careless oversights are more likely to occur.  Thanks Frank.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes this could happen :)

Comment: One up vote, way up!